# Refreshing table Editor with table item in swt

Tags: java, swt

Hello i have a following code for swt table

```
private Table   folderAssociationTable;
private TableItem            item;
private TableEditor          editor; 

folderAssociationTable = componentsRenderer.createTableWidget(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI  | SWT.FULL_SELECTION, 2, true);

        folderAssociationTable.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                event.height = 20;
            }
        });

        componentsRenderer.createTableColumWidget(folderAssociationTable, SWT.CHECK, "Item", 80);
        // add a column to display source folders
        componentsRenderer.createTableColumWidget(folderAssociationTable, 
                SWT.LEFT, PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(QTLConstants.SOURCE_FOLDER_COLUMN_LABEL), 200);
        // add a column to display target folders
        componentsRenderer.createTableColumWidget(folderAssociationTable,
                SWT.LEFT, PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(QTLConstants.TARGET_FOLDER_COLUMN_LABEL), 200);
```

and then adding table data in this fashion

```
item = new TableItem(folderAssociationTable, SWT.NONE);
                            editor = new TableEditor (folderAssociationTable);

                            Button button = new Button(folderAssociationTable, SWT.CHECK);
                            button.setText("item "+ (i+1));
                            button.pack();
                            editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize ().x;
                            editor.setEditor(button, item, 0);

                            item.setText(1, folderlist[i]);    // add source folder to the first column of the table
                            item.setText(2, targetFolderPath);  // add target folder to the second column of the table
                            sourceTargetFolderMap.put(folderlist[i], targetFolderPath);
```

I have remove button on this page outside table component , on its action Listener i am removing selected row from table , but in this case when table is getting updated only table items are updated but table editor remain at same position , how can i refresh both table editor and table items on click of remove button.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the example given in the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableEditor.html)? Add this to your `ActionListener`:

```
// to close the old editor
Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
if (oldEditor != null) oldEditor.dispose();

// add some logic if you want to open the editor again on a different row
```