# Adding content to table viewer dynamically

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I am implementing table viewer like this

```
folderAssociationTable = componentsRenderer.createTableWidget(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI  | SWT.FULL_SELECTION, 2, true);

        folderAssociationTable.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                event.height = 20;
            }
        });
        tableViewer  = new TableViewer(folderAssociationTable);
        tableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
        tableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());


        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("CheckBox");
        column.setWidth(100);
        checkBoxColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, column);


        column = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Source Folder");
        column.setWidth(200);
        sourceFolderColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, column);

        column = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Target Folder");
        column.setWidth(200);
        targetFolderColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, column);
```

now i want to add conent to this table , first column i want to add checkbox, and in another two columns want to add string values dynamically in for loop , how can i add these content to Table Viewer .

Answer (score 0):

First, if you just want to show checkboxes, strings and images which you set, you don't need `TableViewer`. Use a `Table` instead! Viewers are useful if you need something more complex, such as showing arbitrary Java objects.

1. If you want to add checkboxes, use [`CheckboxTableViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/CheckboxTableViewer.html) and an [`ICheckStateProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ICheckStateProvider.html). You'll need to create your table with `SWT.CHECK` style.
2. To add values, you need to set some input for your viewer. In case of `ArrayContentProvider`, this is just an array or a collection:

   ```
   // ModelObject is whatever type of objects you want to show. Maybe just String...
   List<ModelObject> inputList = new ArrayList<ModelObject>();
   // build the list
   while (...) {
       ModelObject newObject = ...
       inputList.add(newObject);
   }

   tableViewer.setInput(inputList);
   ```

   If you need to change the list later, call `tableViewer.refresh()`.

For the rest, see [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html).

Comment: Hello Alexey , I have a table inside which i am implementing to table viewer , one for checkbox ir, CheckBoxTableViewer and another one normal TableViewer For String Component, so On the Basis of entries of string component i want to add checkboxes , how can i do that

Comment: No, you should never have two table viewers for one table, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: so alexey , how can i handle this situation in my case i want to add two simple strings to two columns and check box in that row based on the count i wnat to do these things dynamically , the solution you suggested above i have tried it but when i was taking string array like this     String[] folderInfo = {folderlist[i],targetFolderPath1};
                            tableViewer.setInput(folderInfo);        the folderlist[i] and targetfolder path was getting added in first column itself which is meant for checkbox , so please elaborate on this situation and how can i add checkbox in 1st col

Comment: and in case of simple swt Table , i am facing this issue that why i implemented TableViewer                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701116/refreshing-table-editor-with-table-item-in-swt

Comment: First, checkbox will appear automatically if you add `SWT.CHECK`. If you are using `ArrayContentProvider`, every element of your input goes into a separate row. You'll need to do something like `String[][] folderInfo = new String[] { new String[] {folderlist[i],targetFolderPath1} }` and add a `TableLabelProvider` which takes `String[]` as elements.